# ActiveMQ Classic - unable to browse or send messages to any queues in console page

Tags: java, queue, activemq-classic

I am trying to browse or send messages to queue through ActiveMQ QA console page, but I'm getting the below error page from console, and below are the error logs,

ActiveMQ Classic version: 5.13.3 and Java - 1.8.

```
2023-12-07 09:06:53,669 | INFO  | Connector vm://localhost started |        org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | qtp2112135199-8255672
2023-12-07 09:06:53,674 | WARN  | Failed to add Connection ID:######-37764-1698915314642-4:122 due to java.lang.SecurityException: User name [admin] or password is invalid. | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection | ActiveMQ VMTransport: vm://localhost#243-1
2023-12-07 09:06:53,675 | WARN  | Security Error occurred on connection to: vm://localhost#242, User name [admin] or password is invalid. | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Service | ActiveMQ VMTransport: vm://localhost#243-1
2023-12-07 09:06:53,676 | INFO  | Connector vm://localhost stopped | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | qtp2112135199-8255672
2023-12-07 09:06:53,678 | WARN  |  | org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler | qtp2112135199-8255672
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /browse.jsp at line 19
```

```xml
16: --%>
17: <html>
18: <head>
19: <c:set var="pageTitle" value="Browse ${requestContext.queueBrowser.JMSDestination}"/>
20: 
21: <%@include file="decorators/head.jsp" %>
22: </head>
```

Is there any config files to be updated for the user admin? and getting this error for all the users configured in activemq server.

I tried installing ActiveMQ Classic locally and verified all the config files and `activemq.xml` file. There is no issue with the installed broker.

Comment: ActiveMQ Classic 5.13.3 was released in May 2016 - over 7 years ago now. I recommend you upgrade to at least [the latest 5.x version](https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/download/) (i.e. 5.18.3 at this point). If you can reproduce it there then please [open a bug report here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ).

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is the web console attempting to connect to access messaging layer.

You have a local environment or configuration issue. I downloaded a clean ActiveMQ 5.13.3 and started it up and was able to access the webconsole and login with the default admin account.

Check the conf/credentials.properities to make sure the username and password matches the server-side values in conf/users.properties.

Details:

- conf/credentials.properties contains the client-side messaging account username and password used by the web console to connect to the broker.
- conf/users.properties contains the server-side messaging queue account usernames and passwords (usually for apps)
- conf/jetty-realm.properties contains the server-side web console login information (usually for humans)

Note: In ActiveMQ 6.x, this has been simplified as the web-layer and messaging server-side layer now share conf/users.properties.

Comment: Hi, the configuration files are looking good and having correct credentials configured when comparing the user.properties and credentials.properties files.